# Drawing an ellipse at an angle between two points in Python

Tags: python, numpy, geometry, linear-algebra, trigonometry

I'm trying to draw an ellipse between two points. So far, I have it mostly working:

[image: Arc Angle]

The issue comes with setting the ellipse height (`ellipse_h` below).

```py
    x = center_x + radius*np.cos(theta+deg)
    y = center_y - ellipse_h * radius*np.sin(theta+deg)
```

In this example, it's set to -0.5:
[image: Ellipse Height]

Can anyone please help me rotate the ellipse height with the ellipse? Thank you!

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def distance(x1, y1, x2,  y2):
    return np.sqrt(np.power(x2 - x1, 2) + np.power(y2 - y1, 2) * 1.0)

def midpoint(x1, y1, x2,  y2):
    return [(x1 + x2) / 2,(y1 + y2) / 2]

def angle(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    #radians
    return np.arctan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1)

x1 = 100
y1 = 150
x2 = 200
y2 = 190
ellipse_h = -1
x_coords = []
y_coords = []

mid = midpoint(x1, y1, x2, y2)
center_x = mid[0]
center_y = mid[1]
ellipse_resolution = 40
step = 2*np.pi/ellipse_resolution

radius = distance(x1, y1, x2, y2) * 0.5
deg = angle(x1, y1, x2, y2)
cos = np.cos(deg * np.pi /180)
sin = np.sin(deg * np.pi /180)

for theta in np.arange(0, np.pi+step, step):
    x = center_x + radius*np.cos(theta+deg)
    y = center_y - ellipse_h * radius*np.sin(theta+deg)
    x_coords.append(x)
    y_coords.append(y)

plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")
plt.title("Arc between 2 Points")

plt.plot(x_coords,y_coords)
plt.scatter([x1,x2],[y1,y2])
plt.axis('equal')

plt.show()
```

Comment: y2 should be 190 according to your graph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution is to describe the ellipse by its [standard parametric equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse), as you effectively did. However, under the assumption that it is centered on the origin of the coordinate system, it becomes straightforward to then apply a rotation to its points using a [2d rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) and finally apply a translation to position it on its true center. This gives the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# extreme points along the major axis
x1, y1 = 100, 150
x2, y2 = 200, 190

# along minor axis 
height = 15 

# number of points
n = 100

# center
x_c, y_c = (x1 + x2)/2, (y1 + y2)/2

# width (major axis) and height (minor) of the ellipse halved
a, b = np.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)/2, height/2

# rotation angle
angle = np.arctan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1)

# standard parametric equation of an ellipse
t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n)
ellipse = np.array([a*np.cos(t), b*np.sin(t)])  

# 2d rotation matrix
R = np.array([[np.cos(angle), -np.sin(angle)],
              [np.sin(angle),  np.cos(angle)]])  

# apply the rotation to the ellipse
ellipse_rot = R @ ellipse

plt.plot(x_c + ellipse_rot[0], y_c + ellipse_rot[1], 'r' ) 
plt.scatter([x1, x2], [y1, y2], color='k')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

See the output for different heights:

[image: ellipse_outputs]

Following your comment, for the limiting case of the circle, you need to specify `height = np.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)`, so that `a = b`.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Incredible, thank you!! Is there any easy way to determine at what height will be a perfect circle?

Comment: This is so helpful, thank you. I tried plotting `height = np.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)/2
`, but this is what I got: https://imgur.com/a/iHWdUnt